# A quote from "Java Threads" book about volatile keyword

Tags: java, volatile

I was just wondering if someone could explain the meaning of this:

> Operations like increment and
>   decrement (e.g. `++` and `--`) can't be
>   used on a volatile variable because
>   these operations are syntactic sugar
>   for a load, change and a store.

I think increment and decrement should just work fine for a volatile variable, the only difference would be every time you read or write you would be accessing from/writing to main memory rather than from cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java Language Specification does not have atomic operations for the `++` and `--` operators. In other words, when you write code in the following manner:

```
a++;
```

the Java compiler actually emits code that is similar to the set of steps below (the actual instructions will vary depending on the nature of the variable):

1. Load the operand onto the stack using one of the operations for `load`ing data.
2. Duplicate the value of the operand on the stack (for the purpose of returning later). This usually accomplished using a `dup` operation.
3. Increment the value on the stack. Usually accomplished using the `iadd` operation in the VM.
4. Return the value (obtained in step 2).

As you can observe, there are multiple operations in the VM for what is commonly thought to be an atomic operation. The VM can ensure atomicity only upto the level of an individual operation. Any further requirement can be achieved only via synchronization or other techniques.

Using the `volatile` keyword, allows other threads to obtain the most recent value of a variable; all read operations on a variable will return the recently updated value on a per-instruction basis. For example, if the variable `a` were to be volatile in the previous example, then a thread reading the value of `a` would see different values if it were to read `a` after instruction 2 and after instruction 3. Use of `volatile` does not protect against this scenario. It protects against the scenario where multiple threads see multiple values for `a` after instruction 2 (for instance).

Comment: @Vineet Reynolds, if boolean flag = true; is an atomic operation then why do we need to make it volatile at all? Is it because when thread switching happens and thread B starts to run instead of A, and B sets the value of flag to false then if flag is volatile only then A would be able to see its updated value (which is false) otherwise it would see its cashed version of flag (which is true)?

Comment: @Abidi, using volatile ensures that if a thread were to update the flag (to false), then another thread that reads the value of the flag (after the update), will see the updated value. This is what is meant by visibility; changes made to a variable are made visible to other threads only after the atomic operation. If the variable was not marked as volatile, then yes, the second thread would see an older value despite the update. You could think of it this way, in certain allowed scenarios, volatile can be used to synchronize access to a variable, without acquiring a lock.

Comment: @Vineet Reynolds That's helpful. Just wondering if a shared variable is not declared as volatile, does a reader thread ever try to update its local copy of that variable from memory?

Comment: @Abidi, it would depend heavily on the optimizations performed by the compiler (JIT). The synchronization with main memory happens only when necessary - when a monitor is entered or exited. If I have to reword this, reads and writes of variables maybe reordered in a manner different from program order; volatile ensures that reads and writes happen in the order depicted in source, and that the JVM is prevented from using local caches to operate on these variables.

Comment: @Vineet Reynolds As we know a++ is not an atomic operation but I think flag = false is not atomic either. Would it not require "loading" the variable value from memory and then "storing" it back in the memory. I think in Java loading and storing are two atomic operations. Please comment.

Comment: @Abidi, the JLS states this "Writes to and reads of references are always atomic, regardless of whether they are implemented as 32 or 64 bit values." in chapter 17.7. You ought to be looking at the JVM opcodes generated by the compiler if you want to determine what is going on.

Comment: @Abidi, in the case of your example statement `flag = false`, the assignment operation is atomic, for the value of flag will be either the new value, or the old value. This is because the assignment operation is actually triggered by the store operation, which happens to be a single operation. The read/load operation in the previous step has no effect on atomicity of assignment; an older value might be read, but the assignment is still atomic - it cannot be interrupted once it has started.

Answer (score 8):

`volatile` variable **only** ensures [visibility](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.com/2007/08/atomicity-visibility-and-ordering.html) . It does not ensure [atomicity](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.com/2007/08/atomicity-visibility-and-ordering.html). I guess, that is how the statement should be interpreted.

Answer (score 7):

I think you're taking the quote out of context.

Of course `++` and `--` **can** be applied to volatile variables. They just won't be atomic.

And since `volatile` *often* implies that they must be handled in an atomic manner, this is counter to the goal.

The problem with `++` and `--` is that they might *feel* like they are atomic, when indeed they are not.

Doing `a = a + 1` makes it (somewhat) explicit that it is not an atomic operation, but one *might* (wrongly) think that `a++` is atomic.

Comment: According to my understanding it says boolean volatile flag = false would work fine. Does it mean flag = false is atomic?

Comment: @Abidi: yes, simple assignment to a `volatile` variable is always atomic (the same is true for non-`volatile` primitive variables, except for `double` and `long`, btw).

Answer (score 1):

Volatile does not garanty atomicity in an opeartion that involves multiple steps.

Look at it this way it I am reading a value and that is all am doing, the read operation is an atomic operation. It is a single step and hence the use of volatile here will be fine. If however I am reading that value and changing that value before writing back, that is a multistep operation and for this volatile does not manage the atomicity.

The increment and decrement opeartions are multi-stepped and hence the use of the volatile modifier is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Nope -- you use "volatile" to indicate that the variable can be changed by an external entity.
This would typically be some JNI C code, or, a special register linked to some hardware such as a thermometer. Java cannot guarantee that all JVMs on all architectures can will be capable of incrementing these values in a single machine cycle. So it doesnt let you do it anywhere.